# Simulate File Structure in URL

Tags: node.js, url

I have content with a hierarchical structure which is stored in a database. I want to have the URL reflect the path to the current element. E.g. if I wanted to represent a database of animals, I might want a URL to be: animals.com/kingdom/phylum/class/order/family/genus which would show a list of species in that genus.
How can I accept requests to a URL matching that format, parse it, and show the appropriate page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself rather than use a framework, you can use `url.parse()` to extract the path from a url, and then use `split()` to create an array from the path element.

```
var url = require('url');

var myUrl = "http://animals.com/kingdom/phylum/class/order/family/genus";
var myPath = url.parse(myUrl).path;
var elements = myPath.substr(1).split('/');
console.log(elements); // [ 'kingdom', 'phylum', 'class', 'order', 'family', 'genus' ]
```

You might consider using a framework like Express that offers robust routing options for this stuff. For example, in Express, you could do something like this:

```
app.get('/animal/:kingdom/:phylum/:class', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Kingdom: ', req.params.kingdom);
  console.log('Phylum: ', req.params.phylum);
  console.log('Class: ', req.params.class);
  res.send('Hello animal, lover!');
});
```